# "Unknown class item in Interface Builder file"

Tags: ios, ios6, segue, popover

I have the segue connection to 6 to 7 freeform popover windows within ViewController.  Every time the freeform window opens associated with either of two classes, I get an error (or warning) message that says "**Unknown class item in Interface Builder file**" in the Output window.  That's the exact message I get.  I've read a lot of topics related to this unknown class warning.  The thing is that I don't have that 'item.'  The names of the classes that are associated with this warning message is **ItemViewController** and **UpdateViewController**.  Even when ViewController segue-connects the second one, the message is the same - unknown class item.  Whether or not the message is an error or a warning indicator, application performance is not affected at all.  Everything works fine.  Anyway, what I have done so far is the following.

1. Going to TARGETS > Build Phases > Compile Sources to make sure that all classes are listed.
2. Somebody suggests that we insert "-all_load -ObjC" to Other Linker Flags.  I've done it.
3. Adding [item class] to appdelegate applicatoindidfinishlanching method...  I can't since I don't even have 'item.'

Could anybody figure out what's causing this non-life-threatening message?

Thank you

Comment: did you copy paste from some other project? You missed to change the File's owner class.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response.  I'm not so sure, but I may have dragged one of these freeform windows over from another project.  If that's the case, how can I fix a problem?

Comment: select each object in each xib and check for correct class name attached to it.

Comment: Thanks.  I've done so, already.

Comment: so no where you find Incorrect class name?

Comment: Nope.  I have nothing called item.m or item.h anywhere in the problem in question.  The closest thing is ItemViewController.

Comment: i am not saying in codes.  I am saying in IB.

Comment: I have IBOutlet UITextField *itemField1 in both classes.  There is also one variable named NSString *itemtsecs.  That's all.

Comment: `IBOutlet UITextField *itemField1` these all the programming/codes part. I am saying the GUI. Where you create button by drag-n-drop. Storyboard images etc.....You see views, etc. Select each view and on the inspector check its class.

Comment: Whoa...  I opened the Document Outline drawer and clicked on one of the items.  For some reason, 'item' was inserted to the class field.  Thank you.  You've saved my life.